# Need help in node.js Jade

Tags: mysql, node.js, rest, raspberry-pi, pug

I would like to seek help on displaying mySQL records in node.js Jade. I have followed the basic tutorial of node.js Jade and able to get it work by displaying default index.jade but when I start to implement mySQL connection link and function in my index.js, it display none and shows no data received on browser. Hope you guys could help me out with it as soon as possible, thanks in advance, guys.

**This is my app.js:**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('static-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

app.use(favicon());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);

/// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

/// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});

module.exports = app;
var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Listening on port %d', server.address().port);
});
```

**This is my routes/index.js:**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mysql = require('mysql');

var conn = {
   host: 'localhost',
   user: 'user',
   password: 'password',
   database: 'rest_api',
   port: '3306'
};

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
   exports.index = function(req, res) {
         var connection = mysql.createConnection(conn);
         var query ='SELECT sensorId, sensors, pinNo, sensorsType FROM sensorInfo';
         connection.query(query, function(err, rows, fields) {
                   if(err) throw err;
                res.render('index', { title: 'Sensor REST API', 'items': rows });    
         });
   };
});

module.exports = router;
```

**This is my /views/index.jade:**

```
extends layout

block content
    h1= title
    p Welcome to #{title}
    table
        tr
            th Sensor ID
            th Sensors
       th Pin Number
       th Sensors Type
        -each item in items
            tr
                td=item.sensorid
                td=item.sensors
      td=item.pinNo
      td=item.sensorsType
```

**This is my sensorInfo structure:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sensorInfo` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sensorId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sensors` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `pinNo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sensorsType` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
```

**This is my records which I wanted to display it out from my sensorInfo:**

```
--
-- Dumping data for table `sensorInfo`
--

INSERT INTO `sensorInfo` (`id`, `sensorId`, `sensors`, `pinNo`, `sensorsType`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'Red LED', 7, 'Switch ON/OFF'),
(2, 2, 'Blue LED', 11, 'Switch ON/OFF'),
(3, 3, 'Green LED', 13, 'Switch ON/OFF');
```

Comment: Looking to narrow things down here - Is anything at all being output to the browser? If so, are you getting any returned rows from `connection.query`?

Comment: No output to the browser and for returned rows, not sure how, Kelz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the exports call from your router function - from

```
exports.index = function(req, res) {
    var connection = mysql.createConnection(conn);
    var query ='SELECT sensorId, sensors, pinNo, sensorsType FROM sensorInfo';
    connection.query(query, function(err, rows, fields) {
              if(err) throw err;
           res.render('index', { title: 'Sensor REST API', 'items': rows });    
    });
};
```

to

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection(conn);
var query ='SELECT sensorId, sensors, pinNo, sensorsType FROM sensorInfo';
connection.query(query, function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.render('index', { title: 'Sensor REST API', 'items': rows });    
});
```

Comment: Wow it works, Kelz. Now it can only display title but never display my mySQL records , Kelz.

Comment: If your query is not throwing an error then it may not be inserted correctly. See if it is returning any rows by adding a `console.log(rows);` line before your res.render - if its not then there may be some other issue with your MySQL setup.

Comment: It able to prompt me back after inserting console.log(rows), Kelz. But still no records been display on browser, Kelz.

Comment: I don't understand the comment - what does prompt me back mean?

Comment: Sorry for bad english, what I meant is I can see the console.log(rows) result when I node app.js but when I see my browsers, it only appear title but never mySQL results, Kelz

Comment: Okay great, so that means you are getting the rows out of the database! Sounds like its just a Jade syntax problem. Try to figure out what is wrong with your each loop in jade.